# Use one for-each inside another one xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have problem with XSL transformation. I will using xml file to sending documents which will contains headers so, I need to use a for-each inside another one to create a list of chapters with any level of Headers, but it´s not working. Thanks for help.

XML

```
<Chapters>
    <Chapter>
        <Heading1Lvl>
            <Heading1LvlName>heading1nameFirst</Heading1LvlName>
            <Heading2Lvl>
                <Heading2LvlName>heading2name</Heading2LvlName>
                <Text typeOfText="basic">BasicText</Text>
                <Text typeOfText="important">Important</Text>
                <Text typeOfText="link">Link</Text>
            </Heading2Lvl>
        </Heading1Lvl>
    </Chapter>
    <Chapter>
        <Heading1Lvl>
            <Heding1LvlName>heading1nameSecond</Heding1LvlName>
            <Heading2Lvl>
                <Heading2LvlName>heading2nameSecond</Heading2LvlName>
                <Heading3Lvl>
                    <Heading3LvlName>Heading3First</Heading3LvlName>
                    <Text typeOfText="basic">BasicText1</Text>
                    <Text typeOfText="important">Important1</Text>
                    <Text typeOfText="link">Link1</Text>
                </Heading3Lvl>
                <Heading3Lvl>
                    <Heading3LvlName>Heading3second</Heading3LvlName>
                    <Text typeOfText="basic">BasicText2</Text>
                    <Text typeOfText="important">Important2</Text>
                    <Text typeOfText="link">Link2</Text>
                </Heading3Lvl>
                <Heading3Lvl>
                    <Heading3LvlName>Heading3third</Heading3LvlName>
                    <Text typeOfText="basic">BasicText3</Text>
                    <Text typeOfText="important">Important3</Text>
                    <Text typeOfText="link">Link3</Text>
                </Heading3Lvl>
                <Text typeOfText="basic">BasicText</Text>
                <Text typeOfText="important">Important</Text>
                <Text typeOfText="link">Link</Text>
            </Heading2Lvl>
        </Heading1Lvl>
    </Chapter>
</Chapters>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="Chapters">
<div style="padding-top:10%">
    <xsl:for-each select="Chapter/Heading1Lvl">
        <xsl:value-of select="Heading1LvlName"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Heading1Lvl/Heading2Lvl">
            <xsl:value-of select="Heading1LvlName"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Heading2/Heading3Lvl">
                <xsl:value-of select="Heading3LvlName"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code:

1. In the XML the second `Heading1LvlName` is erroneously named `Heding1LvlName`.
2. In the XSLT in the body of the first `for-each` your current node already is `Heading1Lvl`, but you try to select it again with `Heading1Lvl/Heading2Lvl` which, so remove the double.
3. In the body of the second `for-each` your current node is `Heading2Lvl`, but you try to select `Heading1LvlName` instead of `Heading2LvlName`
4. The same current node error as in 2. The current node is `Heading2Lvl` and you try to select it again with `Heading2/Heading3Lvl`. Just use `Heading3Lvl`

After fixing all this, your template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Chapters">
    <div style="padding-top:10%">
        <xsl:for-each select="Chapter/Heading1Lvl">
            <xsl:value-of select="Heading1LvlName"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Heading2Lvl">
                <xsl:value-of select="Heading2LvlName"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Heading3Lvl">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Heading3LvlName"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```